# flutter Dropdown send selected data to database

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I managed to connect an API with Dropdown Search and show the data when selecting it, but I can't send the selected data to DB, I tried to put the controller --TextFieldProps-- but it didn't work,
this is my codemwhat is the correct method to send the data to the DB

```
DropdownSearch<UserModel>(
          onChanged: (value) {
            con.nomEquipo;
          },
          //validator: (v) => v == null ? "required field" : null,
          asyncItems: (String? filter) => getData(filter),
          clearButtonProps: ClearButtonProps(isVisible: true),
          popupProps: PopupProps.menu(
            showSelectedItems: true,
            itemBuilder: _customPopupItemBuilderExample2,
            showSearchBox: true,
            searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
              controller: con.nomEquipo,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  onPressed: () {
                    //_userEditTextController.clear();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          compareFn: (item, selectedItem) =>
              item.etiqueta == selectedItem.etiqueta,
          dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
            dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Equipo',
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.fillColor,
            ),
          ),
          //dropdownBuilder: _customDropDownExampleMultiSelection,
        ),
```

with this I connect to the API

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getData(filter) async {
var response = await Dio().get(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
);

final data = response.data;
if (data != null) {
  return UserModel.fromJsonList(data);
}

return [];}
```

this is the model

```
class UserModel {
final String etiqueta;
final String name;

UserModel({
required this.etiqueta,
required this.name,
});

factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
 return UserModel(
  etiqueta: json["title"],
  name: json["title"],
  );
 }

static List<UserModel> fromJsonList(List list) {
 return list.map((item) => UserModel.fromJson(item)).toList();
}

///this method will prevent the override of toString
String userAsString() {
return '#${this.etiqueta} ${this.name}';
}

///custom comparing function to check if two users are equal
bool isEqual(UserModel model) {
return this.etiqueta == model.etiqueta;
}

@override
String toString() => name;
}
```

Comment: You have only getData method which just provides data to show on dropdown. What you need is another API endpoint AND a method to send data to your DB using the new endpoint

Comment: @MinjinGelegdorj the error is in the controller, when I send it to the DB it arrives empty, and with a "print" it also shows empty

Answer (score 0):

1st Change your Model :

```
import 'dart:convert';

EmployeeModel employeeModelFromJson(String str) => EmployeeModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String employeeModelToJson(EmployeeModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class EmployeeModel {
    EmployeeModel({
        this.etiqueta,
        this.name,
    });

    String etiqueta;
    String name;

    factory EmployeeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EmployeeModel(
        etiqueta: json["etiqueta"],
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "etiqueta": etiqueta,
        "name": name,
    };
}
```

Then

---

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getData(filter) async {
var response = await Dio().get(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
);

final data = response.data;
if (data != null) {
  return employeeModelToJson(data); //Change here
}

return [];}
```

---

you can the Model Class Name "EmployeeModel" to your Desire One

Comment: I tried it like this example but it didn't work, it has an error --employeeModelToJson--